# .NET form wrong size when program launched

Tags: .net, forms, visual-studio, size

I've got a strange/annoying problem in .NET. When I design a form in visual studio (2013 pro) and size it appropriately the size changes when I click on run/debug as shown in the picture below (left hand side shows it in form designer at the correct size and right hand side shows what it looks like when I click run).

[.NET form size changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJJ10.png)

I have tried different settings on the 'autoscale mode' function but nothing significant changes. When I set autosize to true the window is made tall enough but at the expense of the status bar at the bottom (see below).

[autosize enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVCOV.png)

My machine has a 4k screen - could this be causing the problem I'm seeing? How do I correct this? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: No, that is the correct size.  Gives you a preview of what your program will look like on a user's machine without a fancy monitor.  You can ignore this problem a while longer by declaring your app [to be dpiAware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034).  Even though it clearly is not.  If you want real help with this then you have to show code, not pixels.

Comment: Hi Hans. I added a manifest as you suggested on the linked post but the issue persists. If I run the project on another PC (with standard HD display) it's fine. It only started doing this after I did a minor change on the form (altered some text), before that it was fine on the 4k display. What code would you like me to share?